# Keras training and trainable attribute in BN Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

As stated [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/)

> However, in the case of the BatchNormalization layer, setting trainable = False on the layer means that the layer will be subsequently run in inference mode (meaning that it will use the moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch, rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch).

If I set `trainable = False` initially then it will make the model run in inference mode i.e. `training = False` as stated in the official docs above. But, what will happen if I reset `trainable = True` after the above step? Will the `training` attribute will be reset to `True`? or it will continue to run in inference mode?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, I got the answer from [here](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/)

> When you unfreeze a model that contains BatchNormalization layers in order to do fine-tuning, you should keep the BatchNormalization layers in inference mode by passing training=False when calling the base model. Otherwise the updates applied to the non-trainable weights will suddenly destroy what the model has learned.